# The import java.util.Stack conflicts with a type defined in the same file

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Stack;     //error
public class Stack {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stack<String> stk = new Stack<String>();

        stk.push("apple");       //error
        stk.push("banana");

    }
}
```

It shows error on the import line and `stk.push` line

Comment: Put yoursels in the compiler's shoes: is `Stack<String>` your otn `Stack` or `java.util.Stack`? Give a different name to your class.

Comment: What is the question? You posted some code and and a compile error (with clear message IMO) -- recommended to take the [tour], check [ask], and other points from the [help]

Comment: By the way, `java.util.Stack` is a legacy class. Its Javadoc tells you so, and recommends using a `Deque` implementation instead.